# Comparing generic struct types

Tags: generics, swift, types, struct

How do I determine whether two instances of a generic struct are of the same type?

For example, given the following struct:

```
struct FooBar<T> {
    let variable: T
    init(arg: T) {
        variable = arg
    }
}
```

And the following snippet:

```
let foo = FooBar(1)
let bar = FooBar(1.0)
let baz = FooBar("1")
```

How can I determine whether `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` are of the same or different types?

---

```
func areExactType(x: FooBar) -> Bool {
    return self.dynamicType === x.dynamicType
}
```

This gives

> Type 'Foo' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

---

```
func areExactType(x: FooBar) -> Bool {
    return self.dynamicType === x.dynamicType
}
```

This gives

> Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(Foo.Type, Foo.Type)'

---

```
func areExactType(x: FooBar) -> Bool {
    return self is x.dynamicType
}
```

This gives three errors:

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

(this wants to put a semicolon between the period and 'dynamicType')

> Expected identifier in dotted type

and

> Expected expression

Comment: I just found this question after google searching.  Future me thanking past me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking some inspiration from [Sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26878416/2792531), I came up with this solution:

```
func sameType<L,R>(left: L, right: R) -> Bool {
    if let cast = left as? R {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This works even if nested within a function accepting generics:

```
func compare<T,U>(foo: T, bar: U) -> Bool {
    return sameType(foo, bar)
}
```

But it does have some of the downfalls that Sebastian's answer mentioned.  Namely, if you've retrieved your values from an Objective-C collection, they'll both have a type of `AnyObject`.  Moreover, if we nest my `sameType` function within a function whose arguments are not generics, such as:

```
func compare(foo: Any, bar: Any) -> Bool {
    return sameType(foo, bar)
}
```

The `sameType` function here will always return `true`.  The type of `foo` and `bar`, as far as `sameType` is concerned, is `Any`, rather than whatever most specific type I could potentially downcast it to.

---

It's also probably worth noting that if I try nesting this as an instance method, Xcode crashes.  Read that again, **Xcode crashes**.  Not "produces undesired results".  The application crashes.

For example:

```
func sameType<L,R>(left: L, right: R) -> Bool {
    if let cast = left as? R {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

struct Foo<T> {
    func sameType<U>(bar: U) -> Bool {
        return sameType(self, bar)
    }
}

let x = Foo<Int>()
let y = Foo<Float>()

if x.sameType(y) {
    println("x is a y")
}
```

This code snippet crashes Xcode.  I have no idea why... but it does...

If we instead write:

```
if sameType(x,y) {
    println("x is a y")
}
```

Xcode compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 13):

### Edit:

Sorry for the premature answer, it actually doesn't work, because the compiler will choose the function for different types when called from within another function:

```
func foobar<T,U> (lhs: Foo<T>, rhs: Foo<U>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.sameType(rhs)
}
```

---

#### If you stay in pure Swift territory, the following will work:

Given a simple generic struct

```
struct Foo<T> {
    let v : T
}
```

You can define a function `sameType` that takes to `Foo`s of the same type and just return `true`:

```
func sameType<T> (a: Foo<T>, b: Foo<T>) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and overload the function with two different `Foo`s:

```
func sameType<T,U> (a: Foo<T>, b: Foo<U>) -> Bool {
    return false;
}
```

The compiler will choose a method based on the argument type:

```
let a = Foo(v: 1.0)
let b = Foo(v: "asdf")
sameType(a, b) // false
sameType(a, a) // true
```

This works the same way with instance methods on the struct:

```
    func sameType (other: Foo) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func sameType<U> (other: Foo<U>) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

---

#### This can have unexpected results if you mix Swift and Objective-C or have to rely on the dynamic type for other reasons:

```
import Foundation
let x = NSArray(object: 1)
let y = NSArray(object: "string")
sameType(Foo(v: x[0]), Foo(v: y[0])) // true
```

The result is true because `because Foo(v: x[0])` has type `Foo<AnyObject>`

Comment: It works in a very limited case, otherwise useless. Can I down vote my own answer?

Comment: Still can be useful in some specific situations

Comment: @Sebastian I have found a slight improvement on your answer.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Swift 3.0: "Argument labels don't match the available overloads."

Comment: To me, your answer is a little confusing. I can't understand which part is correct and which part is wrong. Which part you know wrote wrong intentionally and which part you wrote wrong intentionally to point out to a flaw. Can you make an edit?

Answer (score 2):

If I haven't misunderstood, you don't want to know if variables of type `FooBar` are of the same type (because they are), you want to check whether they are using the same generic type.

Since the struct already contains a property of the generic type, you can use it for type comparison, rather than using the struct itself:

```
func areExactType<U>(x: FooBar<U>) -> Bool {
    return x.variable is T
}
```

I've tested in a playground, and it works with basic data types, arrays, dictionaries etc.
The downside is that in order for it to work, the struct must have a property of the generic type.

Comment: Using the struct itself differentiates appropriately between Foo<T> and Foo<U>

Comment: Yeah I agree with that, but in the end what you're looking for is to find out whether `T == U`. It's just a different way to solve the problem. I see that you have not marked any answer as the solution, so I thought you are looking for alternatives.

Comment: But if your struct is of multiple generic types, your way quickly gets complicated. Moreover, what if the type isn't a publicly accessible variable?

Comment: The answer is based on the sample code you provided - it's not universal, and I agree that it gets complicated when the generics are more than one. As for accessibility, private variables are accessible, as long as the `x` parameter is of the same type (which always is in our case)